# How can I set a c# TextBox to disabled but still have the original text styling instead of grayed out text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, textbox

So for the program I'm writing I have an overview of notes the user created. This I created with `TextBox`es that are generated from database values. I want the user to not be able to enter and change anything in this overview.
I tried to use `tb.ReadOnly = true;` but this doesn't disable the entering of the textbox.
After that I tried `tb.Enabled = false;` but this applies a gray out to all the text.

Is there any way to remove this gray out or just make the `TextBox` unchangeable without any visual difference?

Comment: If you need them to be disabled always, you can try to use `Label`s instead of `TextBox`s. They have a slightly different appearance but maybe it will suit you.

Comment: oh of course. How did I not think of that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a label with border style as FixedSingle, flat style as Flat, and set padding to 5,5,5,5.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a NuGet package such as [Guna UI](https://gunaui.com/) to add custom controls. Using Guna, you can use the `Control.DisabledState`:

```
textBox1.DisabledState.FillColor = Color.White;
textBox1.DisabledState.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Note: changing a UI control's disabled state to make it appear enabled is in general, bad practice. This is because a user may try to use the TextBox and get frustrated because the computer will not let them use it.

Or alternatively, you could use a `Label` instead of a `TextBox`.